# Ethernet connection dropped, still shows unplugged

Tags: networking, windows-8, drivers, wired-networking

I was using my Windows 8 desktop when it randomly defaulted to using my wireless connection. I was watching videos online at the time, and nothing was near the tower itself. Since it has gone down, I have been unable to get it working again. In both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 it shows that the cable is not connected even though I have tried the following, in no specific order:

- Restart computer
- Shutdown and start computer
- Shutdown, unplug, wait 30 min, plug back in, and restart (saw in another forum)
- Disable and re-enable adapter through Device Manager
- Uninstall and automatic reinstall adapter through Device Manager
- Install newest drivers direct from manufacturer
- Disable Remote Kernel Adapter in Device Manager
- Boot to Ubuntu 13.04 via USB thumb drive
- Unplug and re-plug physical cable
- Replace network cable

The most confusing part of this so far is that it shows it is disconnected in Ubuntu as well, where most posts I ran across showed that the adapter works in one or the other.

The adapter is as follows:
*Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, RTL8168D*

As previously mentioned, it is running on a Windows 8 desktop computer with 8GB of RAM, 1+TB of storage space, an AMD hexacore processor built by HP. Other items of note are that I am on a college campus and thus have no access to the router or switch it is connected to. Wireless connections still work, but I have to use my laptop because of the Cisco NAC Agent used by my campus (doesn't have the desktop wireless registered as a valid MAC address).

Thank you anyone who can help... and I hope I don't have a dead network adapter on my hands (especially since it shows up).

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the problem has worked itself out after not working for over 2 days. Nothing special was done to the computer in the mean time, but if anyone wants to contribute other ways to fix this problem normally, please do.